# Get width and height of img and add it to it's nearest parent with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, parent

I've figured out how to get the width and hight of an image using javascript. My question is how do I apply the width and height to it's nearest parent in this case it's li using javascript.

```
<ul>
    <li> <img src="img1.jpg" /> </li>
    <li> <img src="img2.jpg" /> </li>
</ul>
```

The js i'm using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var pic = $('img');
    var w = pic.width();
    var h = pic.height();

    pic.removeAttr("width"); 
    pic.removeAttr("height");

    $('ul li').css('width',w);
});
```

Right now it is only getting the width and height of the first image and applying it to every li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below has been modified to demonstrate its effectiveness:

CSS:

```
li {
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="one"> <img src="img1.jpg" width="50" height="80" /> </li>
    <li id="two"> <img src="img2.jpg" width="70" height="50" /> </li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Change" id="change">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#change').click(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        e = $(this);
        dim = [e.width(),e.height()];
        e.parent().css({width: dim[0], height: dim[1]});
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kfnhh/

Simply remove the click event handler and the code should be easily implemented in your environment.

Comment: Thanks @RobB, this worked! Is it possible to add the widths together and apply it to the ul?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
$('img').each(function () {

    var pic = $(this) ;
    var w = pic.width();
    var h = pic.height();

    pic.removeAttr("width"); 
    pic.removeAttr("height");

    pic.parent().css('width',w)
})
```

Didn't try but the idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to it:

```
pic.closest("li").css({'width' : w , 'height' : h});
```

Answer (score 0):

.parent() will get you the parent of what ever control you are using it on. In your case the following should get you the parent control of your image control.

```
// jQuery 
$(this).parent()

// Javascript
element.parentNode
```

Comment: I'm looking for a javascript solution, .parent() is jQuery.

Comment: I'm trying to push myself to write more js :)

Comment: @Inv Briscoe I guess that makes sense. If that is the case though you should try to write the whole thing in js :P

Comment: @Inv Briscoe I have updated my answer but I am sort of confused. Why would you want to use straight javascript when you are already using jquery in your solution above?

Answer (score 0):

To change as little as possible:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var pic = $(this);
        var w = pic.width();
        var h = pic.height();

        pic.removeAttr("width"); 
        pic.removeAttr("height");

        pic.parents('li').css('width',w);
    });
});
```

Would that work?